# Copy Output from Unit test to artifacts

Tags: unit-testing, teamcity, artifacts

Some of my unit tests produce output files. The question is: Is it possible to copy these files to the artifacts?

I already tried to locate the generated files and I found them in the TeamCity Buildagent Temp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have looked a little more into the usage of parameters.
Using the paramater %system.teamcity.build.tempDir% did the trick. All I did was adding the following line to the artifcats box:

```
%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%\**\Out\*.sql => Sql-scripts
```